# Meta reputation on Android app

Tags: bug, reputation, android-app, per-site-meta

On the Android app, when I view the list of Meta sites, I get a rep amount for each site:

[image: Meta list]

Is this correct? I don't think I have a rep value for Meta Stack Overflow any longer...

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you have 1.3K** reputation on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571194/rgraham) and thus on [Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/571194/rgraham).

The reputation on per-site meta's are the same as the main site. (and since the split, MSO is a real meta for SO only)

** Something funny though, you rep on SO is 12,835, while the app shows 1.3K... Weird...